# Rails Duplicating Values in Do Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, loops

I have a do loop that goes through and find all records for a user with regards to an event.

The events_rsvp schema has
: user_id
:event_id
:shift_id
:date

with shift_id and date being optional. If an event has shifts, they can sign up for them. Shifts are repeated on all days the event happens and so they end up signing up for the same titled shift on different days. This is where the problem shows up.

If the user signs up for an event on multiple days, it does not duplicate the data, just when signed up for the same titled shift on multiple days.

Here is the relevant view code:

```
<%= form_tag(event_submit_hours_for_volunteers_path(@event.id), :method => :post) do -%>
    <% @volunteers_hours_for_dates.reverse.each_with_index do |volunteers_hours_for_date, index| %>
    <h3>
        Day #<%= @total_event_dates.reverse.index(volunteers_hours_for_date[:date]) + 1 %> - <%= volunteers_hours_for_date[:date].strftime("%B #{volunteers_hours_for_date[:date].day.ordinalize}, %Y") %>
    </h3>
    <table class="add_hours_to_volunteer_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <%= check_box_tag "select_all_#{index}", true %>
                    <%= label_tag "select_all_#{index}", "Attended?" %>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    Volunteer
                </th>
                <th>
                     Shift
                </th>
                <th>
                    Registered Hours
                </th>
                <th>
                    <%= link_to "Assign all &raquo;".html_safe, "#", :title => "Assign all", :class => "assign_all_link"  %>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Actual Hours
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if volunteers_hours_for_date[:volunteers_hours_info].empty? %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        No volunteers for this event yet!
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
            <% volunteers_hours_for_date[:volunteers_hours_info].each do |volunteer_hours_info| %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%
                            should_row_be_selected = false
                            should_row_be_selected = true if params["user_#{volunteer_hours_info[:user].id}_#{volunteers_hours_for_date[:date].strftime("%d_%m_%Y")}"]
                            should_row_be_selected = true if volunteer_hours_info[:amount].to_f > 0
                        %>
                        <%= check_box_tag "user_#{volunteer_hours_info[:user].id}_#{volunteers_hours_for_date[:date].strftime("%d_%m_%Y")}", true, should_row_be_selected %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= image_tag volunteer_hours_info[:user].avatar_url, :size => "40x40" %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= volunteer_hours_info[:user].first_name %> <%= volunteer_hours_info[:user].last_name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <% if not volunteer_hours_info[:shifts].empty? %>
                            <%= volunteer_hours_info[:shifts].collect{|s| s.position}.join(", ") %>
                        <% else %>
                            N/A
                        <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="registeredhours">
                        <% if not volunteer_hours_info[:shifts].empty? %>
                            <%= number_with_precision(volunteer_hours_info[:volunteering_total_hours], :precision => 2, :strip_insignificant_zeros => true) %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= Event::DEFAULT_VOLUNTEERING_HOURS %>
                        <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Assign &raquo;".html_safe, "#", :class => "assign_hours_link", :title => "Assign"  %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= text_field_tag "amount_#{volunteer_hours_info[:user].id}_#{volunteers_hours_for_date[:date].strftime("%d_%m_%Y")}", volunteer_hours_info[:amount], :style => "width:75px; #{volunteer_hours_info[:is_amount_valid] ? nil : 'border:solid 1px red;'}", :class => "add_hours_for_volunteer_text_field", :autocomplete => :off %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

and here's the relevant controller code:

```
def add_hours_for_volunteers
    @event = Event.includes(:rsvp_users).group("users.id").find(params[:event_id])
    event_rsvps = @event.event_rsvps
    authorize! :add_event_hours, @event.organizer
    @volunteers_hours_for_dates = []
    @end_date_to_use = (@event.end_date and @event.end_date <= Date.today) ? @event.end_date : Date.today
    @total_event_dates = @event.get_occuring_dates(@event.start_date, @end_date_to_use, nil, true)
    get_dates_for_current_page.each do |event_date|
        volunteers_hours_info = []
        @event.rsvp_users.each do |user|
            volunteers_hours_info.push get_volunteer_hours_info(user, event_date) if !event_rsvps.collect{|r| r if r.date == event_date and r.user == user}.compact.empty?
        end 
        @volunteers_hours_for_dates.push({:date => event_date, :volunteers_hours_info => volunteers_hours_info})
    end
end
```

Here's a screenshot of what it's doing. You can see how it combines the two shifts and sums the hours, but still displays it under both days.

[image: screenshot of issue]

I tried playing around with the loop with no luck thus far.

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through! I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Could you try trimming it down to a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It will help us to understand the problem, but it will also help you: Often, trimming down to a MCVE is actually enough to make the problem obvious! Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working?  Maybe Kevin is scheduled to volunteer both days.